# Can I move from one TextBox to another TextBox by pressing the enter button on the keyboard?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

I have two files `test.py` and `test.kv`.

I want to move from one TextBox to another TextBox by pressing the enter key. How can this be accomplished?

## test.py

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

Window.size = (500, 330)

class TestScreen(Screen):
    popup = ObjectProperty(None)


class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('test.kv')
        return self.root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test().run()
```

## test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0
TestScreen:

    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        padding : 30,30
        spacing: 10, 10
        row_default_height: '40dp'

        Label:
            text: 'Name'

        TextInput:
            id: name

        Label:
            text: 'Class'

        TextInput:
            id: clas


        Button:
            text: 'Ok'

        Button:
            text: 'Cancel'
```

Comment: Please list any steps you have tried thus far in getting this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to use <kbd>Enter</kbd> to change the focus, I guess you do not want a multiline texinput. Therefore, one option would be use `on_text_validate` event:

> **on_text_validate**
>   Fired only in multiline=False mode when the user hits ‘enter’. This will also unfocus the textinput.

In your kv file you can do something like:

```
#:kivy 1.10.0
TestScreen:

    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        padding : 30,30
        spacing: 10, 10
        row_default_height: '40dp'

        Label:
            text: 'Name'

        TextInput:
            id: name
            multiline: False
            on_text_validate: clas.focus = True   # <<<<<<<<<<<

        Label:
            text: 'Class'

        TextInput:
            id: clas
            multiline: False

        Button:
            text: 'Ok'

        Button:
            text: 'Cancel'
```